# How to add class to elements which are not fully visible in viewport?

Tags: javascript

I have something like a carousel with elements inside of a container with overflow: hidden

[image]

I can scroll left and right and I want to determine which elements are not visible at all or only half is visible (like on this picture) and when add to this invisible and half visible elements a class.

Width of each element is for example 100px but width of container depends on screen size. I can get number of elements which are visible (by dividing `offsetWidth` of container by width of one element)

Alse I know that there is such thing as `getBoundingClientRect()` but not sure how to use it in this case.

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/aqfeqjzg/2/)

Here you can see how I try to implement `getBoundingClientRect` but I can't figure out which elements to target. I want to add class to the div which is partially seen (4th) and if on the first click part of the first div would be seen - to it too.

Comment: Look at the answer with getBoundingClientRect() on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport and comment back here if that's what you needed. -- In that case we'll want to close this question as a duplicate

Comment: @JasonB It kind of does but the problem is I can't get it work right if I use button click to scroll - as it adds class to anelement which is already visible.

Comment: Well then at this point you should modify your question to include a minimal working version of the code and describe how to reproduce that unwanted behavior. Then we'll be able see what you're seeing and hopefully help you out.

Comment: @JasonB updated